# VS Code intellisense/autocomplete with meanjs

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, visual-studio-code, meanjs

I'm pretty new to both MEAN stack and VS Code.

I'm trying to get autocomplete to work in VS Code but no luck. According to the googling I've done, it's supposed to 'just work'.

I have a meanjs.org app (meanjs v0.3.3) but there really isn't any intellisense, not anywhere it really matters at least.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to install the Typescript definition files for the MEAN stack.

First, install [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd).

`npm install tsd -g`

Next, install MEAN stack. You'll need to install each part of the stack separately.

`tsd init
tsd query node --save --action install
tsd query express --save --action install
tsd query angular --save --action install`

**References**

[Github repo for tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd).

[Online search for tsd files.](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/)